# AngularJS loop through JSON and check if multidimensional

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following controller:

```
controller('homepageCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.menu = {
      "Home": "/",
      "Data Sources": {
        "Add": "/datasources/add",
        "Edit": "/datasources/edit",
        "List": "/datasources/list"
      },
      "Test": "/test"
    }
});
```

And the following HTML (JADE)

```
div(ng-controller='homepageCtrl')
        div(ng-repeat='(key, val) in menu')
          {{key}} - {{val}}
          div(ng-repeat='(k, v) in val')
            {{k}} - {{v}}
```

I want to loop through the JSON object but also to check if the current value is another JSON object and if it is then to iterate through it as well.

The code above currently generates:

```
Data Sources - {"Add":"/datasources/add","Edit":"/datasources/edit","List":"/datasources/list"}
Add - /datasources/add
Edit - /datasources/edit
List - /datasources/list
Home - /
0 - /
Test - /test
```

However I want to it generate:

```
Add - /datasources/add
Edit - /datasources/edit
List - /datasources/list
Home - /
0 - /
Test - /test
```

Comment: *Your HTML* is not HTML.

Comment: @arturgrzesiak It's jade, sorry I'll update the question

Answer (score 2):

Why not just using [`ng-if`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angIf):

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, val) in menu">
    <div ng-repeat="(k, v) in val" ng-if="typeof val == 'object'">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Moritz, but val is a json element not an Array

Comment: I have updated the example to check the json Object.

Comment: Why are there no parentheses around `val`?